# How do I get the asset ID of an item from steam with steam web api?

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api

I need to access an item via the "Inspect in game" link. The following example works fine for me.

```py
s = "76561198894741230"
a = "23877666882"
d = "9252865620333928166"
link = steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S{s}A{a}D{d}
```

**Note:** S is the steam id, a is the asset id and d is something weird but I can get this informations from down below.

However I've got the assetID from the market but I couldn't find the assetID in the item information itself. I have the following informations about every skin?

```py
"23881304661": {
    "id": "23881304661",
    "classid": "310777194",
    "instanceid": "302028390",
    "amount": "1",
    "hide_in_china": 0,
    "pos": 1
}
```

and

```py
"310777194_302028390": {
    "appid": "730",
    "classid": "310777194",
    "instanceid": "302028390",
    "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpoo7e1f1Jf2-r3dTlS7ciJgZKJqP_xMq3I2G4E6Z0l0uiRoNvw0VKx_Ec5Zzr0JIWddVJsYV2C-QK2yL3mjMe9uJvXiSw0Vq_FtQA",
    "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpoo7e1f1Jf2-r3dTlS7ciJgZKJqP_xMq3IqWdQ-sJ0xOyU9NSh0FXk_kQ5aj-mI4LAdlU5YVvY_QXsweu9hsW0tc7AwCNiviY8pSGKLM93OtU",
    "icon_drag_url": "",
    "name": "UMP-45 | Urban DDPAT",
    "market_hash_name": "UMP-45 | Urban DDPAT (Battle-Scarred)",
    "market_name": "UMP-45 | Urban DDPAT (Battle-Scarred)",
    "name_color": "D2D2D2",
    "background_color": "",
    "type": "Consumer Grade SMG",
    "tradable": 1,
    "marketable": 1,
    "commodity": 0,
    "market_tradable_restriction": "7",
        "descriptions": [
            {
                "type": "html",
                "value": "Exterior: Battle-Scarred"
            },
            {
                "type": "html",
                "value": " "
            },
            {
                "type": "html",
                "value": "The misunderstood middle child of the SMG family, the UMP45's small magazine is the only drawback to an otherwise versatile close-quarters automatic. It has been painted using a Digital Disruptive Pattern (DDPAT) hydrographic.\n\n<i>By the time you're close enough to notice the pixels it's already too late</i>"
            },
            {
                "type": "html",
                "value": " "
            },
            {
                "type": "html",
                "value": "The Train Collection",
                "color": "9da1a9",
                "app_data": {
                    "def_index": "65535",
                    "is_itemset_name": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "html",
                "value": " "
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Inspect in Game...",
                    "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D9252865620333928166"
                }
            ],
            "market_actions": [
                {
                    "name": "Inspect in Game...",
                    "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D9252865620333928166"
                }
            ],
            "tags": [
                {
                    "internal_name": "CSGO_Type_SMG",
                    "name": "SMG",
                    "category": "Type",
                    "category_name": "Type"
                },
                {
                    "internal_name": "weapon_ump45",
                    "name": "UMP-45",
                    "category": "Weapon",
                    "category_name": "Weapon"
                },
                {
                    "internal_name": "set_train",
                    "name": "The Train Collection",
                    "category": "ItemSet",
                    "category_name": "Collection"
                },
                {
                    "internal_name": "normal",
                    "name": "Normal",
                    "category": "Quality",
                    "category_name": "Category"
                },
                {
                    "internal_name": "Rarity_Common_Weapon",
                    "name": "Consumer Grade",
                    "category": "Rarity",
                    "color": "b0c3d9",
                    "category_name": "Quality"
                },
                {
                    "internal_name": "WearCategory4",
                    "name": "Battle-Scarred",
                    "category": "Exterior",
                    "category_name": "Exterior"
                }
            ]
        },
```

How do I get the assetID of a skin?

Comment: The key and the 'id' value of your first pasted object are the item's asset id. The second object you pasted is an item description which is not tied to a specific asset, thus has no asset id.